# Manual cookie management for 301/2 redirects in Adobe AIR 3.0 mx:HTML

Tags: air

In Adobe AIR 3.0, you can set an `HtmlLoader` to allow you to manage cookies yourself by adding them to the `UrlRequest` headers, i.e. `htmlLoader.manageCookies = false;`

However, if the request is a 301/302 redirect, the cookies are not added from the request, and there is no way I can see of intercepting the request in order to add the cookie headers - the `locationChanging` event has been removed from `HTMLLoader`.

How are you supposed to handle adding self-managed cookies to the request created by a 301/302 redirect?